# PCA: should standardization be applied on features or samples?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, normalization, standardization

I am struggling a little bit with PCA. 
I understand that standardization is an important part of the algorithm but I do not understand which elements should be standardized. Let's say I have a 10x100 matrix X where the 10 rows are the samples and the 100 columns are the features. Each sample is a RGB image considered as an array (my real dataset has 1087 samples, each one with 154587 features).

Should I standardize each feature or each sample? What if I do not take into account the rows and the columns and I simply do this:

```
X_std = (X - X.mean()) / X.var()
```

I can't figure out the reason why I should standardize with respect to the feature, to the sample or to the entire dataset. What I know is that the standard scaler from sklearn by default runs standardization feature-wise making each feature zero mean and unit variance.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can do neither, one, both, or either (in either order--the order matters): it depends on what your data mean and what your objectives are.

Comment: my data are simply rgb images treated as arrays and I do not understand the meaning of standardizing directly the entire dataset with the code above versus a feature-wise or sample-wise standardization.

Comment: Would it be better to standardize sample-wise? Might be duplicate to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/200070/103153)?

Comment: for image processing reasons you might first standardise within the image, to handle lighting variation: the assumption being that each image has "same" range of colours, but only the lighting is changing. see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_constancy#Retinex_theory

Answer (score 1):

You should be standardizing the dataset separated by the features. In other words, if you have a sample space X (n x d) with n samples and d features per sample, you want to view each feature as being independently distributed (in the most simple case).

So, standardize each n-length feature vector X[:, i] where i = 1,...,d

Doing this will make sure that each feature distribution is judged by the model according to the same mean (0) and variance (1). If you were to standardize each sample X[i] where i = 1,...,n, this wouldn't produce anything significant because the features will be likely coming from different distributions. This can be bad if certain features have different number ranges.

For example, if f1 is in a range of (-2, 4) and f2 is in a range of (-10000, 10000), standardizing at a sample level wouldn't make sense because all of the low-range feature values would be compressed into a tiny subspace due to the larger variance caused by higher range features.

Comment: Sorry, but is the independent part really needed? If anything, when doing PCA don't you somewhat want to see the correlation, the direction of the PA?

Comment: The  signal here to the effect that you _should_ or even _must_ standardize is overstated. It is often and perhaps usually a good idea, and not standardizing may produce garbage results dependent on original choices of measurement units or irrelevant variation. But not standardizing can make perfect sense too if units of measurement are consistent across variables and differences in variability are part of the focus.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out the reason why I should standardize with respect to the feature

By no means a complete or authoritative answer... I just wanted to point out that PCA finds the axes that are orthogonal to each other and which explain most of the **variation** in the data. I.e. PCA rotates the data so that the first component captures more variation than the second, the second more than the third etc.

This means that the unit of measure of each dimension matters. If one dimension is "weight" and you measure it in grams, it contributes a lot more to the total variance than if you measure it in kilograms even if the relevance of that dimension ought to be same whatever the unit. If you standardise the dimensions you remove this dependency on the absolute values.

Is this always desirable? In gene expression analyses where rows are samples and columns (dimensions) are expressions, it is common practice to standardise the columns. This is because, typically, what matters is the relative change of genes' expression across samples rather than their absolute expression levels. However, this also means that a very lowly expressed gene gets the same importance as a highly expressed one if their relative change is the same: this may or may not be desirable.